# Telegram bot API. Boolean type vs True type

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

What is the difference between the `Boolean` type and the `True` type described in the official bot API documentation?

I've read the documentation but didn't find any differences.

Comment: Please show us were you see that in the docs

Comment: For example, the User type has the is_bot field with the Boolean type and the is_premium type with the True type. link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Type `Boolean`

This Field will ***always*** be present on the object, with either the `TRUE` or `FALSE` value

---

#### Type `True`

This Field will ***only*** be present if the value is `TRUE`, otherwise, the key will not be available on the object.

---

So to give an example, based on the [`User`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#user) object:

| Field | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| is_bot | Boolean | True, if this user is a bot |
| is_premium | True | **Optional**. True, if this user is a Telegram Premium user |

The `is_bot` will always be there, as the `is_premium` will **only** be there if it's `TRUE`